# Is this usage of "keep" possible?

Tags: grammar

I found this in a book called *The Joy of Mary*.

> **He kept picking his nose, but for the moment his hands were not in his nose.**

Is this "kept picking" part correct?
Does this mean he had a habit of picking his nose but now he wasn't picking his nose?

Comment: You found it... where? (Sorry to keep asking about this, but sometimes, it makes a difference. For example, I might ask, “What does _drove_ mean, in this passage I found: _He drove over the hill_.” Three people might talk about driving a car, until I add a comment that says, “I don't think that's it; I got this from a book called _Phil Mickelson: My Life on the Golf Course_,” or, “I'm not sure that's right, I got this from short story called _Leaving Clifford’s Creek,_ about a long Australian cattle drive.” Oh. Now you tell us.)

Comment: In short, sometimes it's a courtesy, and sometimes it reveals key information. The importance of citing where you pull quotes from is discussed in [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) as well. I've seen several questions (on ELL and ELU) where the only way someone was able to decipher a passage was to look up the original, and read more than what was provided in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct.

> [pick one's nose](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pick_one%27s_nose): To insert a finger or other object into one's nostril to remove obstructions, especially dried mucus.

He has a habit of picking his nose but then at that moment, he wasn't doing that.

Answer (score -1):

*Kept doing* and *keep on doing*, meaning "do something continually", are correct English and you will find them in any dictionary.

> It **kept raining** for days.
>
> The girls **kept laughing** and made me nervous.

I think, in order to understand this use of *keep (on)* + gerund, you could think:

> **keep** the habit of doing something

Or even:

> **keep** fast on the habit of doing something

I can't verify if this is the real historical derivation of this expression, but at least, I think, it makes this expression plausible and understandable.

Comment: I accept that some readers may have a different view and mark a post with a minus point. But there should be a hint what their view is. What's the use of a minus mark if one does not see the other's opinion.